# Jenkins - Could not find artifact org.apache.maven:maven:pom:3.1.0 in Repo

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, compiler-errors

Java 8, maven compile issue on Jenkins

struggling for ages with this one. I can locally build, compile and test everything without a problem. I use same maven command as I use on my Jenkins. I wiped my `.m2` folder so I have same empty repo and still everything fine.

This is the maven command I use:

`(mvn) -U clean install -PTestExecutor -Dheadless=true -C`

this is my `POM`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

        <cucumber.version>7.3.3</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>4.1.4</selenium.version>
        <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
        <assertj.version>3.22.0</assertj.version>
        <commonsmodel.version>5.3.3</commonsmodel.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M6</maven.surefire.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.8.2</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <maven-cucumber-reporting.version>5.7.0</maven-cucumber-reporting.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>failsafe</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>TestExecutor</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                                <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <includes>**/ExecutorTest.java</includes>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!--cucumber report plugin-->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-cucumber-reports</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <projectName>Automation report</projectName>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                                    <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber</inputDirectory>
                                    <jsonFiles>
                                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                                    </jsonFiles>
                                    <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

and this is the full error report on Jenkins output:

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /appl/xxx/jenkins/workspace/Customer_Portal/web-full-suite/pom.xml -s /appl/xxx/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/settings.xml -U clean install -PTestExecutor -Dheadless=true -C
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testing 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/Maven_repo/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.1.0/maven-core-3.1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.1.0/maven-core-3.1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/Maven_repo/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/3.1.0/maven-plugin-api-3.1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/3.1.0/maven-plugin-api-3.1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/io/cucumber/messages/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/Maven_repo/io/cucumber/messages/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/Maven_repo/io/cucumber/messages/maven-metadata.xml (421 B at 20.6 KB/sec)
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.8.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/Maven_repo/org/apache/maven/maven/3.1.0/maven-3.1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/maven/3.1.0/maven-3.1.0.pom
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class org.jfrog.hudson.maven2.MavenDependenciesRecorder$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.828 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-13T16:59:43+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project testing: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx:testing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M6 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M6 -> org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:3.1.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.1.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven:maven:pom:3.1.0 in XXX-Repo (http://nlxxxxcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/Maven_repo) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /appl/xxx/jenkins/workspace/Customer_Portal/web-full-suite/pom.xml to com.xxx/testing/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testing-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /cucumber/cucumber.html to /appl/xxx/jenkins/jobs/Customer_Portal/jobs/web-full-suite/htmlreports/HTML_20Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/cucumber/cucumber.html' does not exist.
Publishing Selenium report...
Copying the reports.
parsing resultFile cucumber/cucumber.html
Unable to parse cucumber/cucumber.html: java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/appl/xxx/jenkins/jobs/Customer_Portal/jobs/web-full-suite/builds/160/seleniumReports/cucumber/cucumber.html; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 10; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
Set result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: All the dependencies where the group starts with `org.apache.maven.*` are simply wrong...you don't need nor are they correct.

Comment: @khmarbaise what do you mean wrong? if you could elaborate that would be so nice. I added every dependency jenkins said to me was missing or cant be found (locally I indeed dont need half of these depencencies since they are transitive I think?). But this Artifactory wont let you download so we have to upload these dependenicies by hand as well.

Comment: As I wrote all dependencies where the groupId starts with `org.apache.maven*` are simply wronge because you don't need them.

Comment: Okay sure i deleted. Do you have any info on my actual problem?